# Some questions about frames

Tags: linear-algebra, frame-theory

I'm studying frames from [this paper](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/133268/files/08_KovacevicC_F%26T.pdf). I have several question that I can't seem to find answer to.

1. Why do we limit the definition on Hilbert space? What property do we need that other spaces don't have?
2. Can I construct an equal norm tight frame from any tight frame? I know that I can make any frame an equal norm frame normalizing its vectors, but if I do that on a tight frame, it seems that I lose tightness
3. At page 21, there is the formula $\sum_{i \in I}\left|\left<x, \phi_i\right>\right|^2 = \tilde\Phi\tilde\Phi^*\lVert x\rVert ^2  $, where x is a vector, $\phi_i$ are the frame vectors and $\tilde\Phi$ is the dual frame. It seems to me that the left side is a scalar, since it's a sum of scalar product, meanwhile the right side is a matrix, therefore they can't be equal. Am I wrong?
4. Lastly, at page 31, they give us Theorem 4.2, after introducing the notion of frame potential, which formula is $FP(\Phi = \{\phi_i\}_{i\in I} = \sum_{i,j \in I} \left|\left<\phi_i, \phi_j\right>\right|^2$, and say that if we have $m \leq n$ vectors in our frame, with n the dimension of the space, the minimum of the FP is n, but if I take orthonormal vector it should be m, and if I take the vector to be orthogonal with a smaller norm it's even less. Same problem for the next point of the theorem.

Comment: Question 1: The Hilbert space setting is the most natural one since the inner product is used in the frame inequality. It is, however, possible to generalize frames to the Banach space setting. (search for Banach frames)
Question 3: I think that this is a mistake, but I haven't read the whole paper so the notation might be introduced somewhere else. What is true is that $\sum_{i\in I}|\langle x,\phi_i\rangle|^2=\langle \Phi \Phi^* x,x\rangle$. Since the matrix $\Phi\Phi^*$ is self-adjoint, this expression is bounded below/above by the smallest/largest eigenvalue of this matrix

Comment: Continued: times $\|x\|^2$. Question 4: This theorem is only true for unit norm tight frames. This is stated in the sentence above Theorem 4.2. (You can also look up the cited reference, where they state this more explicitly)

Comment: Thank you, it seem that I missed the part in which they said they have unit norm.